# Stackoverflow pings Google?

Tags: discussion, google, seo

**How its done that when I publish some post on `stackoverflow.com`, it at once becomes visible in google search?**

Like this
http://www.google.ru/search?q=fill+body+with+images&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Questions about the site itself belong on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Also, this particular question has been discussed earlier (on meta or in SO blog); I'm sure someone finds a link to that soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that your question shows up so quickly on Google is because Google's crawlers knows SO is a high-traffic site, so it keeps its eyes on the site more often, so-to-speak. It works that way for any major, high-content website. As the content produced scales up, and changes happen more often, Google indexes it more often.

Comment: Also, Google probably knows that StackOverflow.com has high-quality, keyword-rich, relevant content. So it gets indexed more frequently than other sites with less relevant content.

Comment: this can easily turn into a SEO tips post :)

Comment: Yeah, except the SEO tips here are not the kind that the SEO bottom-feeders are looking for.  The moral of the story here is: Create content people find useful.

Answer (score 4):

It's because SO has a sitemap (not accessible to normal users, there is an IP check), so google can instantly know what pages have changed and what pages have been added.

Comment: Really, that's awesome!

Answer (score 3):

[It doesn't](http://www.google.com/#q=Stackoverflow+pings+Google&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=1&output=search&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:d&sa=X&ei=XJiKTKOxM9O4jAfFsfnWBg&ved=0CAUQpwU&fp=6052204b889acdd8).

Comment: And now it does ;)